# Можно ли заменить название ключей на ссылки на них, чтобы функцию можно было бы применить и для словаря с другими названиями ключей?

Tags: python

```
Probabilities = {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'G': 0.25, 'T': 0.25}
def WeightedDie(Probabilities):
    import random
    r = random.uniform(0, 1)
    letter = ''
    for symbol in "ACGT":
    if r >= 0 and r <= Probabilities['A']:
        letter = 'A'
    elif r >= Probabilities['A'] and r <= (Probabilities['A'] + Probabilities['C']):
        letter = 'C'
    elif r >= (Probabilities['A'] + Probabilities['C']) and r <= (Probabilities['A'] + Probabilities['C'] + Probabilities['G']):
        letter = 'G'
    elif r >= (Probabilities['A'] + Probabilities['C'] + Probabilities['G']) and r <= (Probabilities['A'] + Probabilities['C'] + Probabilities['G'] + Probabilities['T']):
        letter = 'T'
    return letter
```

Мне нужна функция для случайного выбора событий с заданными вероятностями. Когда я задаю интервалы, я получаю данные по ключу. Однако,  ключи могут по-разному называться, не обязательно ACGT, и тогда моя функция работать не будет. Вот в этом и проблема.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно Вы хотите. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: используйте pep-8 соглашения об именах, если нет особых причин в вашем случае для обратного.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выбрать случайное значение с неравномерным распределением, определённым заданными весами, можно воспользоваться [`weighted_choice(weights)` функцией](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13047806/4279):

```
def WeightedDie(Probabilities): #XXX non pep-8 names!
    letters = list(Probabilities)
    weights = Probabilities.values()
    return letters[weighted_choice(weights)]
```

Это `O(n)` в памяти и во времени подход (что для `n=4` вполне вероятно является достаточно эффективным). В общем случае при большом `n`, чтобы каждый раз все веса не складывать, можно один раз вычислить частичные суммы как показано [в документации для модуля `random`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#examples-and-recipes):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> weighted_choices = {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'G': 0.25, 'T': 0.25}
>>> choices, weights = zip(*weighted_choices.items())
>>> cumdist = list(itertools.accumulate(weights))
>>> cumdist
[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
```

Затем каждый выбор требует только `O(log n)` вместо `O(n)` шагов, используя [bisect модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), реализующий двоичный поиск по отсортированной последовательности:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> import random
>>> x = random.random() * cumdist[-1]
>>> choices[bisect.bisect(cumdist, x)]
'G'
```

В Питоне 3.6, это можно написать как [`random.choices(choices, weights)[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices) или что тоже самое, используя обозначения из кода в вопросе:

```
import random 

def WeightedDie(Probabilities):
    return random.choices(*zip(*Probabilities.items()))[0]
```

Можно несколько значений за раз запросить (передать `k` именованный параметр) и явно задать `cum_weights`, чтобы их заново не вычислять.

[При обсуждении реализации `random.choices()`](https://bugs.python.org/issue18844) были рассмотрены и более сложные методы такие как [alias метод](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method), позволяющий после `O(n log n)` или `O(n)` инициализации получать случайные значения за постоянное время `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Комментарии к вашему коду:

1. У вас случайные числа в диапазоне от 0 до 1, поэтому не нужно проверять, что `r >= 0` (это условие заведомо выполняется)
2. Если не выполнилось условие `r <= x`, то после этого в `elif` уже не нужно проверять, что `r > x` (у вас `r >= x`).
3. Можно обойтись просто циклом по парам ключ-значение с накоплением значения, с которым нужно сравнивать случайное число на каждом этапе. Если случайное число попало в диапазон, то сразу возвращать соответствующий ключ.

Мой вариант реализации:

```
import random

probabilities = {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'G': 0.25, 'T': 0.25}

def WeightedDie(prob):
    r = random.uniform(0, 1)
    x = 0
    for letter, p in prob.items():
        x += p
        if r <= x:
            return letter

print(WeightedDie(probabilities))
```

На практике лучше пользоваться готовой реализацией, например тем вариантом, который предложил ***@jfs***.

Comment: лучше `random.random()` вместо `random.uniform(0,1)` и `r < x` (строгое неравенство, без правой границы). Кстати, в общем случае можно без потери точности складывать, используя алгоритм похожий на [`math.fsum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum)