# Выбрать наугад димер

Tags: python, словари, теория-вероятностей

Добрый вечер!
Дан словарь с вероятностями нахождения каждой буквы на первом и втором месте:

```
profile = {'A': [0.5, 0.1], 'C': [0.3, 0.2], 'G': [0.2, 0.4], 'T': [0.0, 0.3]}
```

Мне нужно, основываясь на их вероятностях, наугад выбрать димер ('AA', 'AC' и тд.)

Я могу получить наугад выбранное не целое число:

```
random.uniform(0, 1)
```

Тогда для первой буквы димера я могу записать следующее:

```
0 to 0.5 —-> 'A',
0.5 to 0.8 —-> 'C',
0.8 to 1 —-> 'G',
```

С учетом того, что мне нельзя использовать ключи 'ACTG' напрямую, потому что название у ключей могут быть и другие, мне нужно написать функцию, которая выберет наугад димер основываясь на вероятностях каждой буквы на каждом из двух мест. Есть какие-нибудь идеи? Уже довольно долго сижу над этой задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор первой и второй буквы совершенно независим:

```
letters = list(profile)
dimer = ''.join([letters[weighted_choice(weights)] for weights in zip(*profile.values())])
```

где [`zip(*matrix)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279) транспонирует матрицу и [`weighed_choice(weights)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13047806/4279) выбирает случайный индекс  в соответствии с заданными весами для текущей позиции. См. [обсуждение weighted_choice() в связанном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599074/23044).

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import random


def dimer(profile):

    # Перевожу данные в структуру с фиксированным порядком элементов
    data = [(k, v[0], v[1]) for k, v in profile.items()]

    # Первый символ
    rnd1 = random()
    acc1 = 0
    for d in data:
        acc1 += d[1]
        if acc1 > rnd1:
            first = d[0]
            break

    # Второй символ
    rnd2 = random()
    acc2 = 0
    for d in data:
        acc2 += d[2]
        if acc2 > rnd2:
            second = d[0]
            break

    return first + second
```

Функция корректно работает, если суммы вероятностей в исходных данных - единицы.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что надо ТС. У него учитывается порядок элементов словаря. А словарь в *Python* неупорядоченный. Порядок элементов в `data` будет разным при разных запусках.

Comment: @kff, нет, у него порядок сохраняется только на том этапе, где он строит интервал распределения вероятностей. После того, как сделан рандомный выбор, порядок уже перестаёт на что-либо влиять.

Comment: Да, действительно... Что-то я тупанул...